# Что значит %d-, %b, -%Y в запросе MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Разбирал запросы товарища и нашел такой запрос

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(hire_date, '%d-'),
LEFT(DATE_FORMAT(hire_date, '%b'), 3), 
DATE_FORMAT(hire_date, '-%Y')) AS hire_date_short_month 
FROM employees;
```

Что значат обозначения после hire_date?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%d - это просто день, что то вроде 05, из даты 1996-01-05

%b - это сокращение месяца, например Jan

%Y - это год в 4х значном виде, 1996

это просто в каком формате представлять дату

Comment: То есть они равняются командам DAY(), MONTH() и YEAR()?

Comment: Нет, не равняются.

Comment: не совсем, DAY(), MONTH() и YEAR() служат именно для извлечения дня - числовые значения, месяца, и года. А DATE_FORMAT является инструкцией для форматирования, которая будет преобразовывать дату в строку с форматом который вы запросили.

Answer (score 1):

Это символы форматирования даты значения из колонки hire_date.

%d - означает день, например: дата 27-12-2023 будет отформатирована до "27-"

%b - название месяца, отобразит 3 буквы, например: в 27.12.2023 будет "Des" в качестве месяца

-%Y - год в формате 2023